# Decompose function of binary matrix into the contribution of individual rows

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

Given a binary matrix, the function I'm trying to decompose is the product of the average values of the columns, i.e.: $f(x) = \prod_n\overline{x_{*n}}$.

For example, suppose I have the following matrix:

$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then the result would be $0.5*0.5=.25$.

I would like to be able to decompose this $.25$ into the sum of each row's contribution. My naïve attempt was to calculate the $n$-th row's contribution as $f(x) - f(x')$ where $x'$ is equivalent to $x$ with the $n$-th row's entries set to $0$ but the results were obviously wrong.

Can anyone help explain what I'm missing?

Comment: But consider $
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ and $
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$
which have the same column averages, but different rows. How would you describe the  "row contributions" for these cases?

Comment: In the first case, the first row is clearly the only one influencing the function, whereas in the other example they contribution of each row should be equal. Does that make sense?